# Understanding the new nullable reference types warning

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

With the nullable reference types enabled, the following line generates a warning:

```
public string ConvertToString(object value) => value.ToString();
```

> warning CS8603: Possible null reference return.

But I'm not sure why. The argument is not nullable, `ToString()` returns `string` and not `string?`, so how is it possible for this code to have a null reference return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-5.0) `Object.ToString` returns nullable string (`string?`).

```
public virtual string? ToString ();
```

So, now the warning become totally clear - your function is declared as returning non-null string, but actually it returns the result of the `ToString` call, which may be null.

**Update:**
After some additional checks we found, that if a project targeting both .NET Standard and .NET 5.0, the Intellisense will show that `ToString` return non-nullable `string`. This is because for .NET Standard [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netstandard-2.1) really says that 'ToString' returns non-null. And looks like that in the described case the Intellisense will peek infromatino from .NET Standard assemblies.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't see where that page says anything about nullable strings. Also, it's declared as `public virtual string ToString()`. And Intellisense shows it as returning type `string`. How would I see this return type from within Visual Studio?

Comment: Please see a declaration block just before `Returns` header. A return value specified there is exactly the `string?`. I also cited this declaration in the answer.

Comment: Yes, I read your answer and understand it. But when I hover my mouse over it in VS, it shows it returns `string`. And when I go to the definition, it shows it returns `string`. Can you see how this might be something I need to understand more clearly? Anyway, a bit more information on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/23466).

Comment: Great link, thank you! I just checked the sample in a latest VS2019 in net core console project. And it showed me the 'string?' return type both in tooltip and after 'Go to definition'. For net FW project I got the 'string' in declaration, but no warning (as expected).  So, I can't understand how it can be acheved that you have the warning and and 'string' declaration at the same time.

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the fact that my project uses `<TargetFrameworks>` to target both .NET Standard and .NET 5.0. I get the nullable reference type warnings just fine. But Intellisense doesn't appear to know anything about it.